# Authenticate user from membership tables in Java

Tags: java, asp.net, membership, sqlmembershipprovider

I have a asp.net web application which is using membership for authentication and authorization. Now I have develop the application in Java which authenticate the user from the same database [i.e. from the membership tables]. How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many frameworks have a security "library" to abstract away the low level stuff.
What framework are you using?
If you aren't using one take a look at Spring and Spring Security.